# Google Play requires Cordova 4.1.1 or later after May 9, 2016 - Cordova CLI - Not working

Tags: android, cordova, google-play-services, cordova-cli

I have posted a new APK file to android but am still getting the Alert that my app is not up to date.  I am confused because as far as I can tell, my app is running 5.1.1.

The alert on the play store is this link.
[Googel Cordova 4.1.1 Alert](http://www.telerik.com/forums/google-play-requires-cordova-4-1-1-or-later-after-may-9-2016)

[Picture from google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiBjy.png)

I am building and compiling on Windows using Cordova CLI.

```
cordova platform ls
  Installed platforms:
  android 5.1.1

cordova -v
  6.1.1
```

\platforms\android\platform_www
cordova.js

```
var PLATFORM_VERSION_BUILD_LABEL = '5.1.1';
```

How do I know what version is actually in my APK file?  According to the alert I am still under Cordova 4.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

first update your cordova installation, then remove android platform and load it again.

Comment: Hi, I have done that a few times, with no luck.

I just found out CordovaWebView is version 3.6.4.  I have to figure out how to upgrade this.

Comment: Finally found my solution

 1. Config.xml changed version 9 to 14 `<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14"/>`
 2. I had a datepicker plugin where cordova was the wrong version in the plugin.xml `<engine name="cordova" version=">=5.1.0" />`

3. New version of cordova no longer uses `ANT RELEASE` to compile release version.  You must use `cordova build android --release`  -- Note he --release parameter.
4. New APK file is in the output apk folder.  Not the BIN folder.
5. Add and remove android platform.

`cordova platform rm android`

    cordova platform add android